# Why is the css for my calendar showing wrong in IE and Firefox?

Tags: css

I am definitely a newbie at CSS and it is causing me all sorts of headaches. I have the following set up for calendar blocks which looks amazing in Chrome:

```css
    /* calendar */
    table.calendar      { border-left:1px solid #999; }
    tr.calendar-row {  }
    td.calendar-day { min-height:200px; font-size:8px; position:relative; } * html div.calendar-        day { height:200px; }

    td.calendar-day-np  { background:#E8EDFF; min-height:200px; } * html div.calendar-day-np { height:200px; }
    td.calendar-day-head { background:#E8EDFF; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; 
            width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-top:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
    div.day-number   { 
        background:#0099FF; 
        position:absolute; 
        z-index:2; 
        top:-0px; 
        right:-25px; 
        padding:5px; 
        color:#fff; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        width:20px; 
        text-align:center;
        border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
        border-left:1px solid #999; 
    }
    td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { 
        width:150px; 
        max-width:150px;
        max-height:75px;
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        top:0px; 
        padding:0px 25px 5px 5px; 
        border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
        border-right:1px solid #999; 
    }
    .ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none;}
                td.calendar-day div.event,  td.calendar-day-np div {
                    overflow-x:hidden;
                    overflow-y:auto;
                    width:200px;
                    max-width:200px;
                    max-height:75px;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                }
```

The HTML is something like this(generated by php):

```
    <tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">7</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">8</div><div class="event">14:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">17:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div></div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">9</div><div class="event">13:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">14:00-PCR Taylorsville / Audiology</div><div class="event">15:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">15:30-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">16:15-Taylorsville Dermatology</div></div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">10</div><div class="event">08:30-Redwood Clinic GI</div><div class="event">10:00-U of U Hospital HTSHTS</div><div class="event">13:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">15:20-PCR Taylorsville / Audiology</div><div class="event">16:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">18:20-Taylorsville Clinic, Instacare </div><div class="event">20:20-Taylorsville Clinic, Instacare </div></div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">11</div><div class="event">13:30-Taylorsville Clinic, Instacare </div><div class="event">17:30-Taylorsville PT Adult</div></div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">12</div><div class="event">09:45-Intermountain Heart Institute IMC</div><div class="event">13:00-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">15:00-PCR Taylorsville / Audiology</div><div class="event">16:30-PCR Taylorsville / Rehab</div><div class="event">17:30-Taylorsville Clinic Instacare</div><div class="event">18:50-Taylorsville Clinic Instacare</div></div>        </td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;"><div class="day-number">13</div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div></td>
```

However, in Firefox, these two properties seem to be ignored.

```
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
```

And in IE, my information starts half way down the page. What can I do to get the same result in all 3 browsers?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  Is there other relevant CSS, like on the `<tr>` or `<table>` tags?

Comment: Please post more code.  Properties like `top: 0px;` look arbitrary and random without a more meaningful context of more code.

Comment: Hungerstar and Izkata, I additional code.  Hope I can get this figured out.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox is probably right here, Chrome is wrong (and IE is probably broken, as usual).

`TD` elements are no block level elements! As you can see in the [Standard CSS for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html), `TD` elements are of type `display: table-cell`. The CSS property `overflow` only applies to **elements that create a box**, those are elements of the type `block`, `inline-block` and `list-item`. The concept of a box is alien to other elements.

You can get Firefox to hide the x-overflow (and add a scrollbar for y-overflow, if required) by placing `DIV` elements into your table cells, since these will create a box. This should still work in Chrome (but I have no idea what it does in IE).

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {
                width:150px;
                max-width:150px;
                max-height:75px;
                top:0px;
                padding:0px 25px 5px 5px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #999;
                border-right:1px solid #999;
            }
            td.calendar-day div,  td.calendar-day-np div {
                overflow-x:hidden;
                overflow-y:auto;
                width:150px;
                max-width:150px;
                max-height:75px;
                white-space:nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="calendar-day"><div>Test1</div></td>
                <td class="calendar-day"><div>Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2<br>Test2<br>Test2<br>Test2<br>Test2</div></td>
                <td class="calendar-day"><div>Test3</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="calendar-day"><div>Test4 Test4 Test4 Test4 Test4</div></td>
                <td class="calendar-day"><div>Test5</div></td>
                <td class="calendar-day"><div>Test6</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be going in the right direction, but I cant seem to get it to work for me.  I added some additional code so you can have a better idea of what I am dealing with.

Comment: @JoelLewis I'm failing to see your problem. Like I said: `TD` elements don't create a box, thus they cannot have an overflow property. You want an overflow property, put everything that should be cut off into another `DIV` and set the overflow properties on that `DIV`. Your sample code is rather useless, since it does not even create an overflow. This is what your code looks on my system in Firefox: http://i43.tinypic.com/dh8f80.png